# pycrypto installation on Mac OS X failing

Tags: macos, python-3.4

I am trying to install pycrypto package on Mac OS X by running following command :

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib sudo -E pip install pycrypto**
```

But it fails and show following error :

> /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot
>   /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g -L/opt/local/lib -Wno-error
>   -L/opt/local/lib -I/opt/local/include -Wno-error build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.4/src/_fastmath.o -lgmp -o
>   build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.4/Crypto/PublicKey/_fastmath.so
>
> ld: library not found for -lSystem
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 5):

```
ld: library not found for -lgmp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

For the error above, the following works for me on Yosemite.

```
brew install gmp
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: Worked on El Capitan too (OSX 10.11.4)

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this by running following command -

CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" pip install pycrypto

Issue was that my default '-isysroot' was pointing to 10.6 SDK and clang file was from 10.9 SDK.

-Gaurav

Comment: this worked for me, thanks! (used sdk 10.11 on osx 10.11.2)

Comment: Thanks.  Changing 10.9.sdk to 10.11.sdk worked for me too.

Comment: For 10.13 I did CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" pip install pycrypto`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on MacOs Catalina and I don't have `/Applications/Xcode.app` folder (I guess because I don't have Xcode App), so I used another SDK path

```
 CFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" pip install pycrypto
```

and it worked.