# Install Fabric error in pyenv

Tags: python, macos, fabric, pycrypto

I want use Fabric when I product my project in AWS Ubuntu. When I read about Fabric, it required python 2.5~2.7, so I create Python virtualenv on Mac OS X:

```
pyenv virtualenv 2.7.5 fabric
mkdir fabric
```

and I run `pip install fabric`

```
(fabric)fabric $ pip install fabric
```

but it has 2 errors

```
Collecting fabric

[...]

configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/config.h
building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/src
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/ -I/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/include/python2.7 -c     
src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o
src/_fastmath.c:1545:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0     is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                      else if (result < 0)
                               ~~~~~~ ^ ~
src/_fastmath.c:1621:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                      else if (result < 0)
                               ~~~~~~ ^ ~
2 warnings generated.
clang -bundle -bundle_loader python.exe -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o -lgmp -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey/_fastmath.so
ld: file not found: python.exe
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1


------------------------------------------------------

Failed building wheel for pycrypto
Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto

Installing collected packages: pycrypto, paramiko, fabric
Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error

Complete output from command /Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/envs/fabric/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/c5/d1_cb4j92f19h5q0_cbv7bpc0000gn/T/pip-build-vsA2vJ/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/c5/d1_cb4j92f19h5q0_cbv7bpc0000gn/T/pip-iE2TRI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/envs/fabric/include/site/python2.7/pycrypto:

clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/ -I/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/include/python2.7 -c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o
src/_fastmath.c:1545:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                        else if (result < 0)
                                 ~~~~~~ ^ ~
src/_fastmath.c:1621:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                        else if (result < 0)
                                 ~~~~~~ ^ ~
2 warnings generated.
clang -bundle -bundle_loader python.exe -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/lib build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o -lgmp -o build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey/_fastmath.so
ld: file not found: python.exe
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

-------------------------------------------------------

Command "/Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/envs/fabric/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/c5/d1_cb4j92f19h5q0_cbv7bpc0000gn/T/pip-build-vsA2vJ/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/c5/d1_cb4j92f19h5q0_cbv7bpc0000gn/T/pip-iE2TRI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/hanminsoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.5/envs/fabric/include/site/python2.7/pycrypto" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/c5/d1_cb4j92f19h5q0_cbv7bpc0000gn/T/pip-build-vsA2vJ/pycrypto/
```

Some people tell me "you should install pycrpto" so I install pycrpto

```
pip install pycrpto
```

but it has the same error when I `pip install fabric`. I found this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970913/pycrypto-installation-on-mac-os-x-failing), so I run:

```
brew install gmp
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
pip install pycrypto
```

but it has the same error and second solution is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937228/on-mac-os-x-easy-install-fabric-and-or-easy-install-pycrypto-fails-due-to-linke)

```
$ bunzip2 gmp-5.0.5.tar.bz2
```

but it has another error:

```
bunzip2: Can't open input file gmp-5.0.5.tar.bz2: No such file or directory.
```

I can't understand why fabric doesn't install...

Comment: Probably not the core issue, but note that `'pycrpto' != 'pycrypto'`

Comment: ummm.... thank you! but `pip install pycrypto` doen't working too

Comment: oh.... my mistake... fabric can install `2.5 < fabric ver < 2.7` i use pyenv 2.6.7 i solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Python <2.7.8. See [pyenv#273](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/273#issuecomment-285038543).

You can fix it by patching `_sysconfigdata.py`:

```
$ export p=/Users/andrei/.pyenv/versions/2.7.6
$ sed -i -e "s#python.exe#${p}/bin/python2.7#g" "$p/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py"
```